# Display div on hover of different element

Tags: html, css, hover, drop-down-menu, visibility

I'm trying to build a css drop down menu.
I have a div `#category_list` which is hidden and I want to display it once user hover over #category_drop list element. I tried

```
#category_drop:hover #category_list {visibility: visible;}
```

But this doesn't work. Can you please suggest any solution?

**My full HTML**

```
<div id="headbar-wrap">
<p id="back-top"><a href="#top"><span></span></a></p>
    <div id="head-bar">
        <h1><a href="http://website.com/">website</a></h1>
        <ul class="main-menu">
            <li><a class="st_nav_menu" href="index.php">Home</a></li>
            <li id="category_drop"><a class="st_nav_menu" href="#">Categories</a></li>
            <li><a class="st_nav_menu" href="top.php">Top</a></li>
            <li><a class="st_nav_menu" href="anti-top.php">Anti Top</a></li>
            <li class="st_add_button"><a href="#">Add Story</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="main-2-menu">
        <li><a><span style="color: red; font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px; line-height: 44px; padding: 0 10px 0 10px;">Website is under construction.</span></a></li>
        </ul>
        <!-- this is a hidden drop down menu -->
        <div id="category_list" style="height: 400px; width: 500px; background: #000; position: absolute; z-index: 999; top: 45px; visibility: hidden;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

js Fiddle of a current situation http://jsfiddle.net/nzC65/2/

Comment: Can you make a http://jsfiddle.net demo?

Comment: @JaredFarrish Added js fidle at the bottom of the post.

Comment: I think you will need to use Javascript: http://jsfiddle.net/nzC65/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that :hover doesn't work for non-anchor (a tag) on older browsers.

Secondly in your code, category_list is not a child of category_drop and hence your CSS will not actually match any elements.

Check this fiddle for a working implementation: http://jsfiddle.net/YT8YR/

Comment: Oh I didn't know that, but still it doesn't work in new browsers either.

Comment: and hover is set on <li> element not <a>

Comment: Please check the fiddle i posted. The hover is set for the <a> tag to ensure it works across all browsers. I've used the display property over the visibility property, but you can change that as needed. Also, I've moved the display setting from inline to a CSS definition.

Comment: That approach occurred to me; no reason it wouldn't work (since `#category_list` is `position: absolute`). I still probably prefer Javascript, but this does work...